# *Send to Instagram* Trick by *100 Cameras in 1*

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, instagram

From Day One I was told that each third-party iOS app was perfectly sand-boxed and therefore there was no way for a third-party app to transfer messages other than some pre-defined urls to another app.

But this *Send to Instagram* trick done by *100 Cameras in 1* just caught my attention. When the user triggers this action, he jumps from *100 Cameras in 1* to Instagram right away (which is OK and could be easily implemented by the url trick mentioned above.) However, what is interesting is that Instagram will display the image just processed by *100 Camera in 1* as if it was displaying a image from its own sandbox.

I understand that Cocoa Touch must have some APIs to support this. My question is, what are they? Are they only limited to images?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edited**: I understand there's the Cocoa Touch URL scheme thing, but if it's the url scheme that did the trick...   the url scheme must contain info of a pointer/reference to the image. Otherwise even if we jump from 100 Cameras in 1 to Instagram, Instagram won't have access to that image.

**Edited (2nd time)**: Though I haven't tried yet, Tom H's answer might finally led to a solution. So I accepted his answer as the final answer. As for unset's answer, unset kept mentioning the url scheme thing (but dude, we all know that. And it's not the switching-between-apps-by-calling-url that confused us. It's how Instagram accessed that image from another app that confused us.) Since unset's answer doesn't provide much useful info and never answered my question to the point, I down-voted his answer, and I suggest those who up-voted adjust your votes accordingly. **Stack Overflow is a great place because we could almost always have answers that are to the point, not because there are people who's answers are nothing wrong but are never really to the point.**

**Edited (3rd time)**: [The official Instagram developer page](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/) now gives the official solution.

> If your application creates photos and
>   you'd like your users to share these
>   photos using Instagram, you can use
>   the Document Interaction API to open
>   your photo in Instagram's sharing
>   flow.
>
> You must first save your file in PNG
>   or JPEG (preferred) format and use the
>   filename extension ".ig". Using the
>   iOS Document Interaction APIs you can
>   trigger the photo to be opened by
>   Instagram. The Identifier for our
>   Document Interaction UTI is
>   com.instagram.photo, and it conforms
>   to the public/jpeg and public/png
>   UTIs. See the Apple documentation
>   articles: Previewing and Opening Files
>   and the
>   UIDocumentInteractionController Class
>   Reference for more information.
>
> When triggered, Instagram will
>   immediately present the user with our
>   filter screen. The image is preloaded
>   and sized appropriately for Instagram.
>   Other than using the appropriate image
>   format, described above, our only
>   requirement is that the image is at
>   least 612px tall and/or wide. For best
>   results, Instagram prefers opening a
>   JPEG that is 612px by 612px square. If
>   the image is larger, it will be
>   resized dynamically.
>
> An important note: If either dimension
>   of the image is less than 612 pixels,
>   Instagram will present an alert to the
>   user saying we were unable to open the
>   file. It's our current policy not to
>   upscale or stretch images to our
>   minimum dimension.

Comment: This is just a theory: Maybe _100 Cameras in 1_ is saving the image (_Photos.app_) and then loading it to _Instagram_

Comment: @Andelo Thanks. I'm still confused. If so, how?

Comment: Have a look at the developer API for instagram: http://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks rckoenes. But I'm more interested in the Cocoa Touch side. Are there any Cocoa Touch API that allow different third-party apps to transfer images (or pointers/references to images) between each other?

Comment: @Angelo Thank you. Your suggestion definitely pointed to the right track.

Comment: Calling out a person who was trying to help you, downvoting, _and_ suggesting that others do likewise? Some might consider that ingratitude, even rudeness.

Comment: @Josh Obviously he was not. I had made it clear in my question (1st paragraph) that I know about the url scheme thing. I was just confused on how Instagram made it to access another app's image. But unset just kept repeating the url scheme thing and avoiding going to the difficult part. Down-voting was not my intention. But down-voting was my only way to tell other people (who has similar problems) that unset's answer, though looks related, actually doesn't help.

Comment: @Josh At the same time, @Angelo's and @Tom H's answers are truly insightful and are brave enough to step into the difficult part of my question. Unlike unset, @Angelo and @Tom H were indeed trying to help me and were not just wanting to gain some reputation by repeating things that were safe but useless. As a result, I up-voted and accepted their answers and thanked them individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone's interested, here's the actual documentation needed to do such a thing:

http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/

Comment: Thanks Fulvio! I now accept your answer as the final solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instagram has registered the [URL scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) `instagram://` (type "instagram://something" in your iPhones safari and hit "open"). Maybe your app has discovered the format to send images into Instagram – [or Instagram provides a documented API](http://instagram.com/developer/).

For the possible parameters, [check this post](http://groups.google.com/group/instagram-api-developers/browse_thread/thread/d25b09c8571f60fc?pli=1).

Comment: Thanks unset. But I'm more interested in the Cocoa Touch side. Are there any Cocoa Touch API that allow different third-party apps to transfer images (or pointers/references to images) between each other?

Comment: No. There is no way to do that. Please check the manual: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW26

Comment: But how could 100 Cameras in 1 did the trick? It's definitely not private APIs since I downloaded the app right from the App Store. Besides, every Instagram API has to be built upon the Cocoa Touch layer. As a result those Instagram references doesn't provide much information.

Comment: Instagram (and 100 cameras in 1) is exactly using the (URL-Scheme-)API described above. There is NO other way to do this. Maybe you want to take a look at this: http://groups.google.com/group/instagram-api-developers/browse_thread/thread/d25b09c8571f60fc?pli=1

Comment: OK. But have you yourself checked those listed Instagram APIs? None of them would do the trick. Or if there's one, which one? And how?

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happening (or what could possibly happen, also thank you Angelo) is first:

100 Cameras in 1 saves the image to Photos.app.
Then, it passes the name/filename/path of the image to Instagram (via the url scheme).
Then, Instagram retrives the photo from Photos.app, and loads it up.

There is probably not a way to do this with things other than images, however if you have a look at the UIDocumentInteractionController class which lets you open files in other apps, to an extent.

Comment: Thanks Tom. You answer definitely pointed to the right track.

Comment: Almost. Basically you save a PNG or JPG image as .ig or .igo, then open the document normally - which will trigger Instragram to launch (as the designated reader for that file-type). Interestingly, you can add a caption too by setting the annotation property on the file with the NSDictionary key "InstagramCaption".